# Code to stop macro when dialog box opens to update link

Tags: vba, excel

I have a totals sheet which contains pre-loaded formulas for future sheets (generated by a macro).  I have a macro which is presses enter on the cells linked to future sheets and refreshes the formula.

However as the future sheets are not yet created, Excel opens a dialog box asking to search for the file which the formula is linked to.  I have to manually press cancel each time to bypass this.  This method isn't ideal as there are thousands of lines.

Is there a way I can build in a code to stop the macro once it hits the first cell which generates the dialog box to open up?

My code is:

```
Sub RefreshCells()
    ActiveSheet.Range("B6:C2999").Select
    Dim r As Range, rr As Range
    Set rr = Selection
    For Each r In rr
        r.Select
        Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
        Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
        DoEvents
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simple external links update with disabled alerts and errors skipping will do what you intend:

```
Sub UpdateLinks()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=ThisWorkbook.LinkSources
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but I tried to insert your code into my macro and it doesn't work.  It still generates a dialog box when it runs and does not stop the macro from running.  I was hoping to get a code built into my original macro to stop the calculation from going further once it encounters the first cell in which is is trying to update a link from a future sheet...

Comment: Have you tried to run this sub standalone, not inserting into your code? `.DisplayAlerts = False` should suppres any output. What are your OS and Excel versions?

Comment: have included this in my spreadsheet as a standalone code now but I can't run two macros at once so it still goes through the opening-of-dialog-box-to-update-links process.  microsoft office 365, excel 2013.

Comment: This code updates all external links for me on Win 7 Excel 2010. So I just supposed that this single macro will complete all the work you intend to do, and any other macro you have will not be necessary for that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do not need to go to cell and hit enter to refresh a formula. You can just give a "Recalculate" command to Excel to recalculate:

> Recalculate formulas that have changed since the last calculation, and formulas dependent on them, in all open workbooks. If a workbook is set for automatic recalculation, you do not need to press F9 for recalculation.

Source: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-formula-recalculation-iteration-or-precision-73a772d5-6224-407c-8029-60a47488b6aa

So you can just send the 'F9' key from your macro:

```
Application.SendKeys "{F9}"
```

Also consider changing manual/automatic update of Excel formulas directly from your macro:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: Thank you.  When I hit F9, my formulas are not updated.  They only update when I go into the cell and hit enter!  I inserted the F9 key into the macro but it doesn't work as I expected...

Comment: Ok. Can you please give a sample of macro code where you generate those formulas? It seems like there is some trouble with that part. Make sure you put formula code to Cell.Formula and do not assign it directly to Cell object.

Comment: i actually typed in the formula myself and didn't use a macro.  Maybe that's where the problem lies.  perhaps a better way is to use a macro to generate the formula.  But being new to coding, I didn't know how to to do this.  My file is basically made up of a totals sheet and lots or other sheets which are sales invoices.  I want to have a running total of the invoices generated.  The problem is that the invoice sheets are going to be generated in the future so I didn't know how to write a macro to automatically pick that up...